# Image is not displayed in server

Tags: php, symfony, wkhtmltopdf

I have created a pdf file. In local, it is working properly and image is displayed in pdf. But in server image is not displayed. I have checked image path and it is perfect. I have attached screen shot which shows Warning: Failed to load 'image_path' (ignore).

Absolute path is like 'https://example.com/app/img/xyz.jpg'.

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wK5K.png)

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Is the image accessible from your webserver? Can you request it using cURL?

Comment: First check you are able to access image using `curl http://example.com/path/to/image.png`

Comment: yes image is accessible with ```curl``` also. But it is not displayed in pdf.

Answer (score 0):

That's not actually a problem with your code, but with a missing dependency of wkthtmltopdf.

If you are using Debian, this can be solved by installing the `libssl1.0-dev` package.

For more information, please check [this issue in the wkhtmltopdf repo.](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/3001)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to give absolute path like  in Linux `home/project/images/abc.jpg.`